# Symfony Lifecycle callbacks doesn't work

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new with Symfony. I would like to use LifeCycle callbacks. I've spent a lot of time to get it to work, but without success. I read documentation and much more sources and made several times that is written there.

I have definition in yml. Then I create entities by orm:generate... This process create for me even empty setUpdateTimestamp() function. I modify this function, but then when I do update, i don't see change.

```
BaseBundle\Entity\Person:
type: entity
table: people
fields:
    id:
        id: true
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
    first_name:
        type: string
        length: 32
        nullable: true
    last_name:
        type: string
        length: 32
        nullable: true
    updatedAt:
        type: datetime
        nullable: false

lifecycleCallbacks:
  preUpdate: [ setUpdateTimestamp ]
```

and

```
/**
 * Person
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="people")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Person extends BaseBundle\Entity\Base\BaseEntity
{
 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
protected $updatedAt;

...........

/**
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function setUpdateTimestamp()
{
    $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
}
```

Where is my problem? Do I something wrong?

EDIT: 
I use for create entities and for create migration file.

```
php app/console orm:generate-super-entities --generate-annotations=1 --regenerate-entities=1 --extend="BaseBundle\Entity\Base\BaseEntity" --super-dest-path="src" --super-dest-namespace="Generated" src
php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff  --configuration src/BaseBundle/Resources/config/doctrine-migrations-config.yml  $@
```

Comment: You mentioned you did migration, can I ask what do you mean by migration? Did you migrate by `mapping:convert` or you mean something else?

Comment: I was wrong, i meant create entities command.

Comment: Use either yml or annotations to define your entity, no need for both

Comment: After many hours I have finally solution. It was to clear APC cache also, not just app/cache. So after apache restart everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realize that in apc cache it can be something also. After restart apache2 service it started to work.